# serde_json to json prints addtitonal String \r and \n in diesel db object

Tags: rust, serde, rust-diesel, serde-json

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd192960ff73f3cc1f2d9ac8525a5531)

```
use serde_json::json; // 1.0.57
fn main() {

let users = vec![Users {
  id : 10,
  username : "test".to_string(),
  password : "pass".to_string()
  }];
 for user in &users {
     println!("I print  id:{},password:{},username:{} ",user.id, user.password, user.username);
 }
 println!("json_serde prints {}",json!(&users));
 
 let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&users).unwrap();
 println!("Different serde: {}",serialized);
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Users {
 pub id: i32,
 pub username: String,
 pub password: String,
}
```

It works perfect but in my server i get this

```
I print  id:4,password:test, username:test
json_serde prints [{"id":4,"password":"test\r\n","username":"test\r"}]
```

The only difference is I get my data from the db

Diesel query

```
    let users = users
    .filter(id.eq(p_id))
    .limit(10)
    .load::<Users>(&connection)
    .expect("Error loading posts"),
```

Actual Users in model.rs

```
    #[derive(Queryable)]
    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
    pub struct Users {
        pub id: i32,
        pub username: String,
        pub password: String,
    }
```

shema.rs

```
 table! {
        users (id) {
            id -> Int4,
            username -> Varchar,
            password -> Varchar,
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered as it is as it is missing important details, like how exactly data are inserted into the database and which versions of the involved crates are used.

Answer (score 1):

I forget to trim my input so serde_json was correct